# React - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I created a react module and then a react app using create-react-app
When I run the App I get the following error in the browser:

*Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.*

Inspecting my app with chrome dev tools I noticed the evidence of the problem: webpack/babel loads my module's node_modules in the browser and so 2 version of react (and any peerDependencies) are there:

[image]

Is there a way to tell to my app to exclude any module's node_modules folder?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you ever manually did `npm install` after creating the project?

Comment: yes many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue following the approach mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6953#issuecomment-496725439) using react-app-rewired and customize-cra.

You can find an example project here: https://github.com/dwjohnston/material-ui-hooks-issue/tree/master

I think this can be useful for others with the same issue.

Ciao

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this error and none of the standard solutions are helping, you may have the same situation as I just had.

My code tried to import a hook from a package that wasn't installed (`@material-ui` in my case). Instead of warning me that the package wasn't installed, I received the above error.

Code sample:

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
const useStyles = makeStyles({
   ...
});
function MyComponent() {
   const classes = useStyles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by editing index.html. Just moved  tag with bundle in the head of the page. I don't know if it's a good solution, but still works

like this

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>Test</title>
            <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The script tag was in the body (moveed it to the head), cause when I started to create the project I just copied it from example.

Comment: Can you add some sample code to show the asker what you mean

Comment: sure, it's updated